ISC Kea equivalent of ISC DHCPD "group" statement
With ISC DHCP (which is EOL) I used to group hosts with the group statement. It was useful to, for example, change a BOOTP filename for all of them at once, or set some parameters for testing. Something like this:
subnet ... {
    ...
    group {
        next-server 10.1.0.101;
        option root-path "/srv/tftp";
        filename "/grub_bib_os_bookworm/x86_64-efi/core.efi";

        host bibkat01 { hardware ethernet 18:66:da:..:..:..; fixed-address bibkat01; }
        host bibkat02 { hardware ethernet f8:b1:56:..:..:..; fixed-address bibkat02; }

    }

    group {
        next-server 10.1.0.101;
        option root-path "/srv/tftp";
        filename "/grub_bib_os_bookworm_ed/x86_64-efi/core.efi";

        host bibkat03 { hardware ethernet f8:b1:56:..:..:..; fixed-address bibkat03; }
        host bibkat04 { hardware ethernet 98:90:96:..:..:..; fixed-address bibkat04; }
    }
}

I'm migrating to ISC Kea and I cannot find an equivalent of the group statement? Is such thing is possible in Kea? I can set this in Reservations for each host, but I cannot find a way to set options for a group of hosts.
